# Lightweight Linux text editor with JSON formatting

Tags: text-editor, json

I am looking for a text editor that will format / pretty print JSON.

I have been using Atom with Pretty JSON, but the performance is terrible since I switched to to a laptop without SSD.

I know EMACS and VI will probably do but I would prefer something that doesn't require a steep learning curve.

Comment: I use Notepad++ with JSON viewer plugin. It's pretty fast and easy to use.

Comment: Forgot to specify that it should be for Linux.

Answer (score 3):

[Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) is a cross-platform proprietary editor that similar to Atom but with better performance. Plugin are written in Python instead of JavaScript. There is also a plug-in called [Pretty JSON](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Pretty%20JSON), but I'm not sure about its relationship with the Atom plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/) is lighter than Atom and provides similar amount of plugins.

Comment: A collogue already suggested that. Is it lightweight?  I assumed it would be quite big.

Comment: @wobbily_col The size is far from Visual Studio, although the name sounds alike. I wouldn't say the amount of plugins is "similar", but I believe there is at least one for JSON formatting.

Comment: It's based on Electron too, so not lite.

Answer (score 1):

[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/) is lite, and has "JS Format" plugin (and several other "Format***" plugins). On Windows, you need also to unpack Python ZIP files to CudaText folder, from its Sourceforge site.